# How can I check-in the dll from a build into TFS 2015 with the new vNext Build?

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a native c++ project that creates a DLL that is then used with a c# project.

Previously I was using some custom actions in XAML to check out the file replace it with the updated binary and then check it back in.

I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing with new "scriptable" vnext build engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the build step that is actually building your C++ project add a new step (Batch Script, Command Line or PowerShell) that calls [Checkout command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw.aspx) then the [Checkin command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx).

Comment: After years of having to trudge through xaml and compile extensions I forgot how simple shelling out to a batch file actually is.